# Use of 'this' in javascript object methods

Tags: javascript, this

I understand function context is a malleable concept in javascript. But why `this` has to be prepended when calling a member method from another in an object?

```
var o = {
     m1: function() {

     },
     m2: function() {
         this.m1(); // works
         m1(); // does not work
     }
};
```

Why can't the `context` be gleaned by the j/s?

Comment: `this` is not so much a "context" as it is a function parameter. Every function call sets `this` (except for arrow functions, which are special).

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't the context be gleaned by the j/s?

This is not a question about can and cannot. The Javascript engine is *designed* to use certain concepts such as for example `scope` and `execution context`. It is difficult to give a full explanation of these concept in just a few lines. But here are the (very) broad lines.

### Scope

Javascript uses lexical scope.

This is a concept defining which variables any given `function` has access to. This is determined by how you *write your code*.  It follows from this concept that any given function has access to variables placed by you:

- in the  global scope;
- in any function containing the function in question.

This can be illustrated by the following example:

```
var one = 'one' //in the global scope

function A () { // access to one and two
    var two = 'two'

    function B () { // access to one, two and three
        var three = 'three'}

        function C () { // access to one, two, three and four
            var four = 'four'
        };
    };
};
```

If you place a `function` as a `value` of an `property` on an `object` it becomes a `method`. A method only has access to the global scope (disregarding functions nested inside a method) and variables inside itself:

```
var one = 'one'

var myObj = { // in the global scope

     myFunctions: {
         myFunction1: function() {}, // have access to one and myObj
         myFunction2: function() {}  // have access to one and myObj
         }
     };
```

That is why you in your example would have to reach `m1` by calling `o.m1()`;

### Execution context

A function always has a `this` value (disregarding arrow functions).

The value of `this` is always *properties inside an object*. The determination of which object depends on the function's execution context. The execution context more specifically depends on the function's *callsite* as the value of `this` will be set to:

- the object (level) containing the call of the function; or if not contained within another function
- the global object

This can be illustrated by an example:

```
var one = 'one'
var myObj = {

    two: 'two',
    three: 'three',
    myFunction: function () { // this points to myFunction, two and three
                    function () { //this points to one and myObj 
                    }
                };
```

Now the above example is actually what can really lead you to think that now you understand `this` and therefore you lower your guards and before you know of it `this` is biting you in your a**. It is ***extremely important*** to remember the part about the function's ***callsite***:

```
var myObj = {
    name: 'myObj',
    myFunction: function() {console.log(this.name)
    };

var anotherObj = {
    name: 'anotherObj',
    notAnotherFunction: myObj.myFunction
    };

myObj.Myfunction(); // myObj
anotherObj.notAnotherFunction(); // anotherObj
```

In the above example *the same function* is called twice but with different callsite's and consequently with different values of `this`.

---

I can recommend you reading [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) series if you want to selfstudy to get to the bottom of amongst others the above concepts.

Answer (score -2):

Okay,
`this` refers to the Object itself relative to the context its used in.
`o` is your Object and `m1` and `m2` are members (methods) of your object.
When calling `m1()` instead of `this.m1()` javascript will look for a function in the same scope (not the object but outside of it).
Its just a short explanation, you can find more here:
[MDN - this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)